# pyinstaller + PySide6 -- WARNING: file already exists but should not:

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, pyside6

When I compile my app I get similar issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66069360/pyinstaller-onefile-warning-file-already-exists-but-should-not)

My warnings look like these:

```
[18136] WARNING: file already exists but should not: 
C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI181362\PySide6\QtCore.pyd
[18136] WARNING: file already exists but should not: 
C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI181362\PySide6\QtGui.pyd
[18136] WARNING: file already exists but should not: 
C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI181362\PySide6\QtNetwork.pyd
[18136] WARNING: file already exists but should not: 
C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI181362\PySide6\QtOpenGL.pyd
[18136] WARNING: file already exists but should not: 
C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI181362\PySide6\QtPrintSupport.pyd
[18136] WARNING: file already exists but should not: 
C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI181362\PySide6\QtQml.pyd
[18136] WARNING: file already exists but should not: 
C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI181362\PySide6\QtQuick.pyd
[18136] WARNING: file already exists but should not: 
C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI181362\PySide6\QtWebEngineCore.pyd
[18136] WARNING: file already exists but should not: 
C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI181362\PySide6\QtWebEngineWidgets.pyd
[18136] WARNING: file already exists but should not: 
C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI181362\PySide6\QtWidgets.pyd
```

inspired by answer from other post i added the following code to my spec file:

```
to_remove = ["QtCore.pyd", "QtGui.pyd", "QtNetwork.pyd", 
             "QtOpenGL.pyd","QtPrintSupport.pyd", "QtQml.pyd", \
             "QtQuick.pyd", "QtWebEngineCore.pyd","QtWebEngineWidgets.pyd", \
             "QtWidgets", "QtOpenGL.pyd"]

to_remove_alt = ["PySide6.QtQuick", "PySide6.QtNetwork", "PySide6.QtPrintSupport", 
                 "PySide6.QtCore", "PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets", \
                 "PySide6.QtQml", "PySide6.QtGui", "PySide6.QtWidgets", 
                 "PySide6.QtOpenGL", 
                 "PySide6.QtWebEngineCore", "PySide6.QtNetwork"]



for b in a.binaries:
      if str(b[1]).rsplit("\\",1)[1] not in to_remove:
          pass
      else:
          print("removed " + b[1])
          a.binaries.remove(b)

    
for b in a.binaries:
      if b[0] not in to_remove_alt:
          pass
      else:
          print("removed " + b[0])
          a.binaries.remove(b)
```

which outputs

```
removed c:\digikwondo\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PySide6\QtQuick.pyd
removed c:\digikwondo\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PySide6\QtOpenGL.pyd
removed c:\digikwondo\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PySide6\QtPrintSupport.pyd
removed c:\digikwondo\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PySide6\QtCore.pyd
removed c:\digikwondo\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PySide6\QtWebEngineWidgets.pyd
removed PySide6.QtNetwork
removed PySide6.QtGui
removed PySide6.QtWidgets
```

now when I start app I still get these warnings

```
[1772] WARNING: file already exists but should not: 
C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI17722\PySide6\QtQml.pyd
[1772] WARNING: file already exists but should not: 
C:\Users\digikwondo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI17722\PySide6\QtWebEngineCore.pyd
```

Why are these last two files(`QtQml.pyd, QtWebEngineCore.pyd`) not removed? (despite being in my lists)

Am I missing something here?

my platform:

```
PyInstaller: 4.5.1
Python: 3.9.2
Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
```

packages installed

```
Package                   Version
------------------------- ---------
altgraph                  0.17.2
auto-py-to-exe            2.10.1
bottle                    0.12.19
bottle-websocket          0.2.9
certifi                   2021.10.8
cffi                      1.15.0
charset-normalizer        2.0.7
cycler                    0.10.0
docopt                    0.6.2
Eel                       0.12.4
future                    0.18.2
gevent                    21.8.0
gevent-websocket          0.10.1
greenlet                  1.1.2
gunicorn                  20.1.0
idna                      3.3
Jinja2                    3.0.2
json2html                 1.3.0
kiwisolver                1.3.2
MarkupSafe                2.0.1
matplotlib                3.4.3
matplotlibqml             0.92.2
numpy                     1.21.3
pandas                    1.3.4
pefile                    2021.9.3
Pillow                    8.4.0
pip                       21.3.1
psutil                    5.8.0
pycparser                 2.20
pycryptodomex             3.11.0
pyinstaller               4.5.1
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2021.3
pyparsing                 3.0.1
pypiwin32                 223
PySide6                   6.2.0
python-dateutil           2.8.2
pytz                      2021.3
pywin32                   302
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0
pyzipper                  0.3.5
requests                  2.26.0
setuptools                57.0.0
shiboken6                 6.2.0
six                       1.16.0
tinyaes                   1.0.1
tornado                   6.1
urllib3                   1.26.7
wheel                     0.36.2
whichcraft                0.6.1
yarg                      0.1.9
zope.event                4.5.0
zope.interface            5.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of trail and error the following code in spec file seem to have done the trick!

```
to_rem = ["PySide6.QtQuick", "PySide6.QtNetwork", "PySide6.QtPrintSupport", 
          "PySide6.QtCore", "PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets", \
          "PySide6.QtQml", "PySide6.QtGui", "PySide6.QtWidgets", 
          "PySide6.QtOpenGL", "PySide6.QtWebEngineCore", 
          "PySide6.QtNetwork"]
      

for val in to_rem:
    for b in a.binaries:
          nb = b[0]
          if str(nb).endswith(val):
                print("removed  " + b[0])
                a.binaries.remove(b)
```

now my app starts and runs fine.